# What are the 'powerful profession mechanics' in light armor?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In Guild Wars 2, you have three types of armor: Light, Medium and Heavy. Scholars wear light armor, Adventurers wear medium armor, Soldiers wear heavy armor.

I get that the heavy armor provides more armor than the lighter versions. Light armor has, and I quote the wiki from Guild Wars 2:

> the least innate protection of all armor classes, a tradeoff for other
>   powerful profession mechanics.

What are these 'powerful profession mechanics'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Elementalists** have only 1 weapon slot, but have different skills for each weapon for each of their 4 elemental attunements, effectively giving them 4 weapon slots compared to everyone else's 2. Water attunement tends to have several healing skills for most weapons (staff in particular can put out quite a bit of healing). Air attunement usually has some evasion & control skills, while earth attunement typically has at least 1 defensive skill.

**Necromancers** have Death Shroud mode, in which damage reduces their Death Shroud life force supply rather than their actual hit points, as well as giving them a set of powerful abilities. They're also the only class with good life steal skills.

**Mesmers** produce clones and phantasms, effectively spamming the battlefield with decoys.

Each light armor class essentially has some profession mechanics that help them stay alive despite their low armor *if* they're played in the style appropriate for the class (though this shouldn't be interpreted as the ability to just stand there and take it the way a heavy armor class can).